# Função recursiva que retorna a soma dos divisores de um número

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Como exercício tive que criar uma função recursiva que retorne a soma dos divisores de um número.

Fiz o seguinte código, mas está dando erro de recursão máxima:

```
def somadiv(n, i = 1, s= 0):
   if i <= n:
       return somadiv(s)
   else:
       if n%i==0:
           return somadiv(s+i)
       else:
           return somadiv(i+1)

print(somadiv(8))
```

Tentei também este código, mas agora retorna `None`:

```
def somadiv(n, i = 1, s= 0):
   if n == i:
        return somadiv(i)
    else:
        if n < i:
            if n%i==0:
                return somadiv(i+1, s+i)
print(somadiv(8))
```

Agora ta dando resultado errado ta retornando o numero anterior a n

```
def somadiv(n, i = 1, s = 0):
    if n == i:
        return s
    else:
        if n < i:
            if n%i==0:
                return somadiv(n,i+1, s+i)
            else:
                return somadiv(n,i+1,s)


print(somadiv(8))
```

Comment: Para evitar manter longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86866/discussion-on-question-by-lucas-suanderhus-funcao-recursiva-que-retorna-a-soma-d) e pode prosseguir lá, caso surjam novas dúvidas/pendências

Answer (score 0):

Solução final

```
def somadiv(n, i = 1, s = 0):
    if n == i:
        return s+i
    else:
        if i <= n:
            if n%i==0:
                return somadiv(n,i+1, s+i)
            else:
                return somadiv(n,i+1,s)


print(somadiv(8))
```

Comment: Quando editei uma vez, falaram que não podia, pois eu taria alterando a pergunta.

Comment: Pelo que entendi isso é uma resposta, pois está funcionando - faltou colocar um texto explicativo, dizendo o que resolveu e como fez pra descobrir

Comment: @nosklo A primeira versão desta resposta não era, veja o histórico de edições